# Concatenated Doc2Vec - calculate similarities

Tags: gensim, word2vec, doc2vec

I have two Doc2Vec models trained on the same corpus but with different parameters. I would like to concatenate the two of them and calculate the similarity of a given input word, choosing the returned vectors from the concatenated model. I read a lot of comments regarding the fact that this method may not be particularly suited for performance improvement and that it might be necessary to change the source code to the KeyedVector class in gensim to enable it. Up to now I attempted to do that using the Translation Matrix but it returns 5 features from the second model and I am not sure about whether it is performing the translations correctly or not.
Has anybody already encountered this issue? Is there another way to calculate the similarity for an input word in a concatenated doc2vec model?
Up to now I have been able to reproduce this:

```
vocab1 = model1.wv
vocab2 = model2.wv

concatenated_vectors = {}
vocab_concatenated = vocab1
for i in range(len(vocab1.vectors)):
    v1 = vocab1.vectors[i] 
    v2 = vocab2.vectors[i]
    vocab_concatenated[list(vocab1.vocab.keys())[i]] = np.concatenate((v1, v2))
```

In order to re-calculate the `most_similar()` top-n features for a passed argument, how should I re-istantiate the newly created object? It seems that

```
.add_vectors(list(vocab1.vocab.keys()), vocab_concatenated[list(vocab1.vocab.keys())])
```

is not working, but I am sure I am missing something.

Comment: Please add [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Gensim has no native utility method for concatenating word-vectors from 2 different sets-of-vectors (`KeyedVectors`-type objects) - but it shouldn't be that hard to implement, as roughly: (1) pick one of the two sets as the one with surviving vocabulary; (2) manually tamper with its internal `vectors` array to create an array that's double-wide (2N dimensions), but includes the original values for its 1st N dimensions; (3) iterate over each word, copying the N dimensions from the 2nd set of vectors into dimensions N to 2N for the 1st set of vectors. Voila! Now one set has all 2N dims per word.

Comment: @gojomo thanks a lot! I managed to concatenate the two arrays but then, if I want to calculate the `most_similar()` on these newly-created larger vectors, how should I instantiate the object? Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you follow the procedure above - so that the concatenated arrays are inside one of the `KeyedVectors` instances as its `.vectors` property, and its dict still points to the right rows for each individual word – the `most_similar()` should still just work.

Comment: @gojomo Yes, it does! thank you very much! I was just wondering whether it's necessary to re-normalize the aggregated vector or not.

Comment: The `most_similar()` will do the internal normalization-optimization that it needs for cosine-similarity calcs as needed - so you may not need to think about it. More generally, whether actual explicit normalization helps at any step, or whether the two sets of vectors (if different-enough in average magnitudes/spacing/etc) should get any extra preprocessing to make their concatenation work better, would be things to try to determine experimentally. This isn't a common-enough technique that I know any strong 'rules-of-thumb' for what's best.